# Find smallest number in given range in an array

Tags: c#, loops, c#-4.0, optimization, comparison

Hi i have an array of size N. The array values will always have either 1, 2, 3 integer values only. Now i need to find the lowest number between a given range of array indices. So for e.g. array = 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 3 3 2. the lowest value for ranges like [2-4] = 1, [4-5] = 2, [7-8] = 3, etc.

Below is my code :

```
static void Main(String[] args) {
    string[] width_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int[] width = Array.ConvertAll(width_temp,Int32.Parse);  // Main Array              
    string[] tokens_i = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_i[0]);
    int j = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_i[1]);
    int vehicle = width[i];
    for (int beg = i+1; beg <= j; beg++) {
        if (vehicle > width[beg]) {
            vehicle = width[beg];
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", vehicle);
}
```

The above code works fine. But my concern is about efficiency. In above I am just taking one set of array range, but in actual there will be n number of ranges and I would have to return the lowest for each range. Now the problem is if there is a range like [0-N], N is array size, then I would end up comparing all the items for lowest. So I was wondering if there is a way around to optimize the code for efficiency???

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a RMQ (Range Minimum Query) and there is several implementation which may fit your scenario.

Here is a nice [TopCoder Tutorial](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/#A%20O(N),%20O(sqrt(N))%20solution) cover a lot of them, I recommend two of them:

Using the notation in the tutorial, define `<P, T>` as `<Preprocess Complexity, Query Complexity>`, there is two famous and common implementation / data structure which can handle RMQ: **Square Rooting Array** & **[Segment Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)**.

Segment Tree is famous yet hard to implement, it can solve RMQ in `<O(n), O(lg n)>` though, which has better complexity than Square Rooting Array (`<O(n), O(sqrt(n))>`)

---

**Square Rooting Array (`<O(n), O(sqrt(n))>`)**

*Note That It is not a official name of the technique nor any data structure, indeed I do not know if there is any official naming of this technique since I learnt it...but here we go*

[image: Image from TopCoder Tutorial]

For query time, it is definitely not the best you can got to solve RMQ, but it has an advantage: Easy Implementation! (Compared to Segment Tree...)

Here is the high level concept of how it works:

Let **N** be the length of the array, we split the array into **sqrt(N)** groups, each contain **sqrt(N)** elements.

Now we use `O(N)` time to find the minimum value of each groups, store them into another array call `M`

So using the above array, `M[0] = min(A[0..2]), M[1] = min(A[3..5]), M[2] = min(A[6..8]), M[3] = min(A[9..9])`

(The image from TopCoder Tutorial is storing the *index* of the minimum element)

[image]

---

Now let's see how to query:

For any range `[p..q]`, we can always split this range into 3 parts at most.

Two parts for the left boundaries which is some left over elements that cannot be form a whole group.

One part is the elements in between, which forms some groups.

Using the same example, `RMQ(2,7)` can be split into 3 parts:

1. Left Boundary (left over elements): `A[2]`
2. Right Boundary (left over elements): `A[6], A[7]`
3. In between elements (elements across whole group): `A[3],A[4],A[5]`

Notice that for those in between elements, we have already preprocessed their minimum using `M`, so we do not need to look at each element, we can look and compare `M` instead, there is at most `O(sqrt(N))` of them (it is the length of `M` afterall)

For boundary parts, as they cannot form a whole group by definition, means there is at most `O(sqrt(N))` of them (it is the length of one whole group afterall)

So combining two boundary parts, with one part of in between elements, we only need to compare `O(3*sqrt(N)) = O(sqrt(N))` elements

You can refer to the tutorial for more details (even for some pseudo codes).

Comment: Your answer will be meaning less and wrong, if the link expires and also if they change the content. So please try to add important notes from the Link, and give the link as reference

Comment: @SHIVANGRANA What should I do? I just give the tutorial reference at first, and someone said my answer is meaningless, now I give some explanation, of course it is according to the reference, and someone said it is completely copied...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `Linq` extension methods.

```
    List<int> numbers = new List<int> {2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2};

    int minindex =1, maxindex =3, minimum=-1;

    if(minindex <= maxindex && maxindex>=0  && maxindex >=0 && maxindex < numbers.Count())
    {
        minimum = Enumerable.Range(minindex, maxindex-minindex+1) // max inclusive, remove +1 if you want to exclude
            .Select(x=> numbers[x])    // Get the elements between given indices
            .Min();                    // Get the minimum among.    
    }
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VQZWoe)

Answer (score 0):

This seems a fun little problem.  My first point would be that scanning a fixed array tends to be pretty fast (millions per second), so you'd need a vast amount of data to warrant a more complex solution.

The obvious first thing, is to break from the loop when you have found a 1, as you've found your lowest value then.

If you want something more advanced.

1. Create a new array of int.  Create a pre load function that populates each item of this array with the next index where it gets lower.
2. Create a loop that uses the new array to skip.

Here is what I mean.  Take the following arrays.

```
int[] intialArray = new int[] { 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 };

int[] searchArray = new int[] { 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
```

So the idea is to find the lowest between positions 0-7.

Start at `initialArray[0]` and get value 3.
Read `searchArray[0]` and get the value 4.  The 4 is the next index where the number is lower.
Read `initialArray[4]` and get the value 2.

etc.

So basically you'd need to put some effort to build the searcharray, but onces it's complete you would scan each range much faster.

Answer (score -1):

Form your looping like the following:

```
int[] inputArray = { 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2 };
int minIndex = 2;
int maxIndex = 5;
int minVal = 3;
for (int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex; i++)
{
    if (inputArray[i] <= minVal)
        minVal = inputArray[i];
}
Console.WriteLine("Minimum value in the Given range is ={0}", minVal);
```

Comment: I'm not the original "down voter" but I also down voted because your solution is not programatically complex, its essencially hard coding. it would be more usefull for everyone to get the minindex for any array not a hard coded human set one.